# Same c++ code sometimes works and sometimes doesnt

Tags: c++, winapi

my c++ code works for a couple of times straight and after few executions it suddenly stops working and throws exceptions (without any changes!), and I cant figure out why.

This is the problematic part of code:

```
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
TCHAR *path;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Startup, KF_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, &path);
lstrcat(path, L"\\calc.exe");
if (CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

}
```

After a few executions, 2 exceptions are thrown on the CreateProcess() line, the first one:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x779D8829 (ntdll.dll) in PS_Down.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77A15890).
```

The second:

```
Exception thrown at 0x77946111 (ntdll.dll) in PS_Down.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000069.
```

It happened to me with a few other projects (that don't include the CreateProcess() func) and iv'e noticed that it always happens when TCHAR and SHGetKnownFolderPath() are involved. 
Any help with understanding how to fix the issue will be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

P.S - I'm new to coding in cpp, so please try to explain accordingly

Comment: This is a textbook case of undefined behaviour. Make a [MCVE] because the problem could be elsewhere. You also need to check for errors in places where you currently don't. e.g. how do you know that `path` is valid?

Comment: What does `SHGetKnownFolderPath` do with the `&path`-argument? Will it reserve memory when passing in a NULL-ptr; will it use it as buffer if the arguments is not NULL?

Answer (score 8):

`lstrcat(path, L"\\calc.exe");` will cause a buffer overrun. `path` is a pointer to array that can contain only folder path, nothing more. You will need to allocate a wide string, append folder path and then file path. Also you will need to check result of `SHGetKnownFolderPath` to determine whether `path` contains a valid pointer and free it later by calling `CoTaskMemFree`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you mind elaborating a bit more on how to make the full string and free path's memory when I'm done with it?

Comment: @Apex Something like `::std::wstring full_path{}; full_path.append(path); full_path.append(L"\\calc.exe");` and `::CoTaskMemFree(path);`

Comment: @apexOr even simpler: `std::wstring full_path{path}; 
  full_path.append(L"\\calc.exe");
  ::CoTaskMemFree(path);`

Comment: @VTT When I do so and change path to full_path in the CreateProcess() func I get an error: "no suitable conversion from 'std::wstring' to 'LPWSTR' exists", how can I include full_path in the func?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks, do you know how to solve the problem I encountered after doing so?

Comment: @Apex Please check [string class reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) prior to asking such basic questions, you only need to call `full_path.data()`.

Comment: @VTT As I said I'm new to programming and don't really understand how to use full_path.data() even after reading about it, would like an explanation if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`path` is allocated with a fixed length by `SHGetKnownFolderPath` so you can't concatenate your executable to it directly. You'd need to use `CoTaskMemRealloc` to expand the space first. You also need to free the memory after you've used it. Similarly, you need to close the handles created by `CreateProcess`.

You could therefore make support classes to handle the resources automatically:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <wchar.h>

// A wide string exception class. perhaps something like this already exist in VS?
class werror {
    std::wstring text;
public:
    werror(const wchar_t* Text) : text(Text) {}
    const wchar_t* what() const { return text.c_str(); }
};

class ConCatToKnownFolderPath {
    PWSTR m_path;
public:
    ConCatToKnownFolderPath(REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid, DWORD dwFlags, HANDLE hToken, const WCHAR* AddToPath = nullptr) :
        m_path(nullptr)
    {
        if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(rfid, dwFlags, hToken, &m_path) != S_OK)
            throw werror(L"SHGetKnownFolderPath failed");

        if (AddToPath) {
            size_t newlen = wcslen(m_path) + wcslen(AddToPath) + sizeof(WCHAR); // place for \0
            size_t newbufsize = newlen * sizeof(WCHAR);

            auto newPtr = CoTaskMemRealloc(m_path, newbufsize);
            if (!newPtr) {
                CoTaskMemFree(m_path);
                throw werror(L"CoTaskMemRealloc failed");
            }
            m_path = reinterpret_cast<PWSTR>(newPtr);
            wcscat_s(m_path, newlen, AddToPath);
        }
    }
    // move works fine
    ConCatToKnownFolderPath(ConCatToKnownFolderPath&& other) noexcept :
        m_path(other.m_path)
    {
        other.m_path = nullptr;
    }
    ConCatToKnownFolderPath& operator=(ConCatToKnownFolderPath&& other) noexcept {
        if (m_path) CoTaskMemFree(m_path);
        m_path = other.m_path;
        other.m_path = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }
    // copy not supported (but could easily be added
    ConCatToKnownFolderPath(const ConCatToKnownFolderPath&) = delete;
    ConCatToKnownFolderPath& operator=(const ConCatToKnownFolderPath&) = delete;

    // automatic free when it goes out of scope
    ~ConCatToKnownFolderPath() {
        if (m_path) CoTaskMemFree(m_path);
    }

    PWSTR data() const { return m_path; }
    operator LPCWSTR () const { return m_path; }
};

struct WProcessWithInfo : PROCESS_INFORMATION {
    WProcessWithInfo(LPCWSTR lpApplicationName, LPWSTR lpCommandLine, LPCWSTR lpCurrentDirectory) {
        STARTUPINFOW si;
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

        if (!CreateProcessW(lpApplicationName, lpCommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, lpCurrentDirectory, &si, *this))
            throw werror(L"CreateProcessWCreateProcessW failed");
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    WProcessWithInfo(const WProcessWithInfo&) = delete;
    WProcessWithInfo(WProcessWithInfo&&) = delete;
    WProcessWithInfo& operator=(const WProcessWithInfo&) = delete;
    WProcessWithInfo& operator=(WProcessWithInfo&&) = delete;
    ~WProcessWithInfo() {
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
    }
    DWORD Wait(DWORD  dwMilliseconds=INFINITE) {
        return WaitForSingleObject(*this, dwMilliseconds);
    }

    operator HANDLE () { return hProcess; }
    operator LPPROCESS_INFORMATION () { return this; }
};


int main() {
    try {
        ConCatToKnownFolderPath path(FOLDERID_System, KF_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, L"\\calc.exe");
        std::wcout << L"Starting " << path.data() << L"\n";
        WProcessWithInfo proc(path, NULL, NULL);
        std::wcout << L"Process started\n";
        proc.Wait();
        std::wcout << L"Process done\n";
    }
    catch (const werror& ex) {
        std::wcerr << L"Exception: " << ex.what() << L"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now it's working. I had a silly bug. Note that I've put the `path` as the first argument to `CreateProcessW` to avoid having to surround the program to start with `"..."`.

Comment: Yes, the calculator starts just fine for me. I changed to `FOLDERID_System` but you used `FOLDERID_Startup` originally. Did you try changing that?

Comment: Yes I noticed and changed it, but calculator still doesn't start for me. However Ive noticed that if I put a CLI exe instead, it works fine under the main console

Comment: Ok,  does it write `Exception`? I've updated the code above to print out the exception too so you can see where it fails.

Comment: Hmm, I think `calc.exe` behaves differently on W10 than on W7. I just tested it on a W10 machine and it starts `calc.exe` but immediately says Process done. Try with `FOLDERID_System ` and  `L"\\notepad.exe"` to see if that works.

Comment: The `calc.exe` process started seems to start a `Calculator.exe` process and then die directly on W10 which is why waiting on that process returns directly.

Comment: Yep it works just fine with notepad.exe, so is calc.exe the problem?

Comment: Well, it makes it harder to wait for it for sure. You would need to find a way to wait for `calc.exe`s child processes too - or alternatively, start the `Calculator.exe` app instead of `calc.exe`.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you got something out of the resource managing part even though waiting for that particular program was trickier than anticipated. :)